# Swift - Duplicated keys with different values

Tags: swift, dictionary, duplicates, key, key-value

My problem is I created a dictionary with String:Int key-values pairs. But when I try to run my playground, it shows me the error of an duplicated key (...the value is different)
But imagine u try to write phone directory and have to add two friends with the same name (...but obviously with different phone-numbers)

```
let addrsbch: [String: Int] = ["Mike": 123435462,"Kevin": 45343, "Simon": 65436, "Micha": 95675756, "Mike": 446346532]

for (name, nr) in addrsbch{
    print("Der Name des Kontaktes lautet: \(name) und die dazugehörige Nummer: \(nr)")

}
```

Comment: BTW, never represent phone numbers as `Int`s. Lots of phone numbers contains `#`,  `*`,`,`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries always one value for one key. If your values are `Int`, then you only have one `Int` per key, period.

However, nothing stops you from having a value of type `[Int]` (a.k.a. `Array<Int>`). At that point, each key still only has one value associated with it (one array), but that value is itself a collection which can store more values (multiple ints).

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary (associated array) has to contain unique keys.
So, obvious is using alternate collection type.
For instance, you can use `Set` of tuples instead:

```
let addrsbch: Set<(String, Int)> = [("Mike", 123435462),("Kevin", 45343), ("Simon", 65436), ("Micha", 95675756), ("Mike", 446346532)]

for person in addrsbch{
    print("Der Name des Kontaktes lautet: \(person.0) und die dazugehörige Nummer: \(person.1)")

}
```

or use struct instead of the tuple:

```
struct Person {
let name: String
let someStrangeNumber: Int
}
```

Comment: But then you lose the lookup ability of a dict, which is pretty much the entire reason to use a dict.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is to use **DictionaryLiteral**
I change your code and it works fine

```
let addrsbch: DictionaryLiteral = ["Mike": 123435462,"Kevin": 45343, "Simon": 65436, "Micha": 95675756, "Mike": 446346532]
for (name, nr) in addrsbch{
print("Der Name des Kontaktes lautet: \(name) und die dazugehörige Nummer: \(nr)")

}
```

also you can use **KeyValuePairs**

```
let addrsbch: KeyValuePairs = ["Mike": 123435462,"Kevin": 45343, "Simon": 65436, "Micha": 95675756, "Mike": 446346532]

for (name, nr) in addrsbch{
    print("Der Name des Kontaktes lautet: \(name) und die dazugehörige Nummer: \(nr)")
    
}
```

Comment: Could u please explain me the function of DictionaryLiteral and KeyValuePairs :)

Comment: @Azad2323 sure but best source is apple and read this content https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary